# Having problems with operators in php for table background color

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to put different background-colors to different categories of the tables. Would anyone recommend me a solution?

Tried using xor, or, and || but doesn't seem to work.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="image-block">
<label '.(($pageCategory == 'promotion')?' class="yellow" ':''or($pageCategory == 'test')?' class="green" ':''or($pageCategory == 'guides')?' class="orange" ':''or($pageCategory == 'reviews')?' class="violet" ':''or($pageCategory == 'class')?' class="blue" ':'').'><a href="'.self::get_category_url($pageCategory).'">'.$pageCategory.'</a> . 
</label>
<img src="'.$pageImage.'" style="min-width:60px;" />
</td>
<td class="text-block">
<h2>'.$postTitle.'</h2> '.((isset($showPageIntro) and $showPageIntro)?'<p>'.self::get_words($pageIntro).'</p>':'').'
<span>'.$postDate.'</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It's not showing the colors that is suppose to be shown, CSS have each of the colors as label.color (.color is the corresponding color above). Nothing is showing.

Comment: Your quotation marks seem wrong in your `<label>`. You may want to consider escaping them.

Comment: @ObsidianAge escaping them like separate each label out? and use the if clause?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ternary operator inside your html tag.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="image-block">
<label class="<?= ($pageCategory == 'promotion') ? 'green' : 'yello' ?>">'.$pageCategory.'</a> . 
</label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

One more thing you can do it. First find out the class before the label tag using `if..else..` condition and then directly assign it.

third way is, pass the result with the class name only from the `php` code. Suppose, you retrieve result from the database and then process the data and pass to html.

Hope so, any method listed above will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    switch($pageCategory){
        case 'promotion':
            $class = 'yellow';
            break;

        case 'test':
            $class = 'green';
            break;

        case 'guides':
            $class = 'orange';
            break;

        case 'reviews':
            $class = 'violet';
            break;

        case 'class':
            $class = 'blue';
            break;

        default:
            $class = '';
            break;
    }

<table>
<tr>
<td class="image-block">
<label class="'.$class.'">
<a href="'.self::get_category_url($pageCategory).'">'.$pageCategory.'</a> . 
</label>
<img src="'.$pageImage.'" style="min-width:60px;" />
</td>
<td class="text-block">
<h2>'.$postTitle.'</h2> '.((isset($showPageIntro) and $showPageIntro)?'<p>'.self::get_words($pageIntro).'</p>':'').'
<span>'.$postDate.'</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's giving me this error code Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) any other advice?

Comment: @ViraphanPaiboolsilp I added echo to the original code but I saw you didn't use it elsewhere. Try it without (i.e. the edited code)

Comment: <label class=""> this is what is showing up in the inspect element in chrome.

Comment: @ViraphanPaiboolsilp check the value of `$pageCategory` to see if its one of those five values in the switch statement

Comment: the values for $pageCategory is giving out the values to match the case but not giving the $class.

Comment: @ViraphanPaiboolsilp hard to say, then. Maybe the switch statement is getting called in the wrong place, or `$class` is getting reset. Try setting `$class` to something in the default block, or putting `die()` statements in the statement to see if the code is even being executed.

Comment: Thank you everyone. it works perfectly now there was a reset in $class so it couldn't display the name.